# Angular Validation $parsers

Tags: validation, angularjs

When we have a controller or ng-model-controller we can do

```
ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){ 
    ctrl.$setValidity('valid', true); 
});
```

and in the end $digest is called automatically and validation renders.
What if I want to validate a field on blur. and I do

```
element.blur(function(){ 
    [validations]
    ctrl.$setValidity('valid', false); 
})
```

and the result don't change on html with elements ng-binded, how to render this change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `ctrl.$setValidity('valid', false);` within [scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    ctrl.$setValidity('valid', false); 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Or better yet, in order to avoid problems further on, use CSS to solve this problem. Let's assume the following code:

```
<textarea ng-model="description" ng-minlength="50"></textarea>
<span class="error" ng-show="myform.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
<span class="error" ng-show="myform.$error.someOtherValidation">Err!</span>
```

When you start typing, Angular starts validation, and errors appear (which is sometimes desirable, but more often, it's not).

What you can do in order not to mess up Angular's internals, is some CSS magic:

```
textarea:focus ~ .error {
  display:none;
}
```

The tilde is a general sibling selector, so as long as you have your fields focused all your errors will stay hidden.

Comment: There is a problem. When you have an error, you don't want to hide it when user selects the input. It should disappear after the correction.

Comment: This has always been a problem I've had with AngularJS.  I don't want my user blasted with errors the second they touch a form.  So, Tomaz's suggestion is a good idea to me.  But, Frizi brings up a good concern.   So my ideal solution is don't show an error until the user blurs.  Then, when they come back to fix it, show the error continuously until it is actually solved.  Maybe add a class on blur that indicates that it was failed once?  "previously-failed".  Then, use CSS to display the error even when focused?